# What preposition could be used to express "by using a bridge"?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

Imagine it's foggy outside. Bob and Michael are trying to get across a river.

> Michael: How can we get across the river?

Bob point to somewhere far away. The bridge can barely be seen in the heavy fog.

> Bob: through that bridge

[image]

I guess it is better to say "There is a bridge over there" though, my concern is about the prepositions.

In this very context, which of the following prepositions is appropriate?

> through that bridge
>
> by that bridge
>
> with that bridge
>
> by using that bridge

Comment: over that bridge

Answer (score 1):

Bob could say 'with', 'by' 'by using', 'over', or 'on'.
I wouldn't use 'through' unless it were a covered bridge.